# How can I perform cumulative calculations over a date range in SQL? (e.g. calculation for 01 uses data from 01, 02 uses 01 and 02, and so on)

Tags: mysql, sql

**Context**

I would like to perform cumulative calculations over a selected date range. (i.e. 2014-07-01 (henceforth referred to as 01 for simplicity) would perform a calculation on data in 01 only. 02 would perform a calculation using data from 01 and 02. 03 would use data from 01, 02, and 03. And so on.)

**Detail**

I have a record of every sale made in a store and whether or not a complaint has been made. It is easy enough to generate the following table with the query below -

```
SELECT 
Date, 
COUNT(*) AS Sales, 
SUM(CASE WHEN ComplaintMade = 'True' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Complaints 
FROM SalesRecords 
WHERE Date BETWEEN '2014-07-01' AND '2014-07-05' 
GROUP BY Date 
ORDER BY Date
```

```
--------------------------------------
| Date       |  Sales  | Complaints  |
--------------------------------------
| 2014-07-01 | 100     | 2           |
| 2014-07-02 | 150     | 6           |
| 2014-07-03 | 180     | 9           |
| 2014-07-04 | 140     | 10          |
| 2014-07-05 | 300     | 15          |
--------------------------------------
```

Calculating the average number of Sales per Complaint is easy enough to calculate by extending this query and selecting the following -

```
COUNT(*) 
/ 
CASE WHEN(SUM(CASE WHEN ComplaintMade = 'True' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) = 0
              THEN 1
              ELSE (SUM(CASE WHEN ComplaintMade = 'True' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END))
              END) 
AS SalesPerComplaint
```

(This shows the number of sales per complaint made (Sales / Complaints), or, if no complaints have been made, the number of Sales (Sales/1))

This would display the following table.

```
----------------------------------------------------------
| Date       |  Sales  | Complaints  | SalesPerComplaint |
---------------------------------------------------------|
| 2014-07-01 | 100     | 2           | 50                |
| 2014-07-02 | 150     | 6           | 25                |
| 2014-07-03 | 180     | 9           | 20                |
| 2014-07-04 | 140     | 10          | 14                |
| 2014-07-05 | 300     | 15          | 20                |
---------------------------------------------------------|
```

What I would like to do is show the cumulative SalesPerComplaint. So, for 2014-07-01, take the Sales for 2014-07-01 divided by the number of Complaints for 2014-07-01. But, for 2014-07-02 take the Sales for 01 *and* 02, divided by the Complaints for 01 *and* 02. And for 03 use the data from 01, 02 and 03. And so on.

So, the first couple of rows of the table would look like -

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------
| Date       |  Sales  | Complaints  | CumulativeSalesPerComplaint |
-------------------------------------------------------------------|
| 2014-07-01 | 100     | 2           | 50                          |
| 2014-07-02 | 150     | 6           | 31.25                       |
-------------------------------------------------------------------|
```

(The CumulativeSalesPerComplaint for 2014-07-02 is now 31.25 because it is calculated using the Sales from both Dates so far (100 + 150 = 250) divided by the number of Complaints from both Dates so far (2 + 6 = 8) (250/8 = 31.25))

*(Please let me know if I could improve this question formatting. I wanted to make this as clear as possible but if I've included too much detail or a confusing structure please let me know and I will gladly improve it. Thank you.)*

My sqlfiddle is at sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9e2ad/5

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you've not already done so (you haven't), provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you've not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1. I'm on a roll.

Comment: I will make a sqlfiddle now. My apologies, I should have thought to do so originally. Thank you.

Comment: My sqlfiddle is at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9e2ad/5

Comment: I don't understand how the fiddle relates to the information provided in the question. And, more importantly, you appear to have no PRIMARY KEY, so this isn't really a table.

Comment: Why not? It is shorter due to limitations in SQLFiddle and only contains the first two rows, but it is exactly the same as is described.

Comment: So it would produce the same result?

Comment: There is no primary key because SQLFiddle limits the number of characters allowed so I only included relevant fields.

Comment: A primary key IS relevant.

Comment: What do you mean? As I stated in the question, I do not know how to perform cumulative calculations on date ranges. 

I took time creating a SQLFiddle with a relevant subset of the data within its constraints, and showed how I would calculate this non-cumulatively. I want to know how to do this cumulatively.

Comment: I really don't think the PK is at all relevant to solving this problem.. maybe his/her PK is a compound key of 20 columns, still want it included?

Comment: How exactly will having a primary key or not affect this question? Obviously the table is much larger in practice but SQL Fiddle poses constraints so I stripped it down to the two relevant fields.

Comment: @OGHaza Rows in an RDBMS table rows have no order. So in the absence of a PRIMARY KEY it is impossible to say which row precedes which, therefore a cumulative problem is (practically) insoluble

Comment: @Strawberry, we are grouping by a field of DATE type. I think this question is entirely clear. If the columns were called "col1", "col2" and "col3" of type VARCHAR you would have a point.

Comment: @Strawberry Yes but as I have stated it is based on Date. Taking the total for Date 1, then on Date 2 using the total from Date 1 and Date 2. A PRIMARY KEY should not affect this at all.

Comment: @OGHaza Apologies for bothering you, is there any way I can improve my post to make it more clear? I try to be as clear as possible but keep getting downvotes with no accompanying criticism and I'm finding it difficult to engage in the community and improve. As an experience user do you have any advice to improve post clarity? Thank you

Comment: Eilidh, I've never asked a question so probably not the one to ask ;) I wouldn't worry about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about this ([SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9e2ad/23))?

In this query, you are joining the distinct dates you have with the data you've already obtained:

```
SELECT sr.uniqueday Date, qry.Sales, qry.Complaints,
SUM(Sales)/SUM(Complaints) CumulativeSalesPerComplaint  
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT(Date) uniqueday FROM SalesRecords) sr
LEFT JOIN (
SELECT 
Date, 
COUNT(*) AS Sales, 
SUM(CASE WHEN ComplaintMade = 'True' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Complaints,

((COUNT(*)) / (CASE WHEN (SUM( CASE WHEN  ComplaintMade = 'True' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END )) = 0 
                                THEN 1
                                ELSE (SUM( CASE WHEN  ComplaintMade = 'True' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ))
                                END)
                            ) AS  SalesPerComplaint 

FROM SalesRecords 
WHERE Date BETWEEN '2014-07-01' AND '2014-07-05' 
GROUP BY Date 
ORDER BY Date DESC
  ) qry ON qry.Date <= sr.uniqueday 
GROUP BY sr.uniqueday
```

The trick is to join the two tables (one containing only the several days, the other with your data) with a join with the condition "qry.Date <= sr.uniqueday", so for a single uniquedate you are joining all the previous rows.

Comment: Thank you! I really appreciate your help. I'm quite new to SQL and this is a bit advanced for me. Would you mind including a bit more explanation please? I'd really appreciate it. Cheers!

Comment: I have just slightly edited the query so Sale and Complaints are not the comulative ones :)

Comment: Very minor thing I'd say is to move the ORDER BY to the outer query (p.s. nice rep)

Comment: If you move the ORDER BY to the outer query, you will get wrong Sales and Complaints fields...

Comment: @lpg, sorry I see what you mean, I'm not used to mysql where you can SELECT ungrouped/non-aggregate fields